# 70s or 80s book about a colony on the moon

Tags: story-identification, moon

Colony on the moon reached by space elevator. Opposing parties fighting for control of space elevator. Etiolated humans living in hidden part of colony.
I have two authors in my head but can't pin down a title by either.

Comment: *"Etiolated"*? ... *Huh?*

Comment: What two authors?  Any detail can be the key when it comes to story ID.

Comment: @Eliza - Welcome to the site. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: @Paulie_D I was assuing that was meant to be "isolated" and some *helpful* tool "fixed" a misspelling for him, but ... it could *just barely* be intended.

Comment: @dmckee -- I can see a very clever SciFi writer using the term.. Etiolation is the process where plants that need light will grow in a way to try to reach it -- usually pale, weak versions of the plant that are just trying to extend to where they may encounter light.  (You will see this sometimes when a plant is badly obscured by a structure or other plants.)  Humans, stuck as troglodytes, could well be said to engage in the same behavior, if, sick and pale, they are 'struggling toward the light.'  **IF** that's what the author meant, it's clever.. But you are right; it's probably a typo :)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the plots of *Jumping off the Planet* and *Bouncing off the Moon* -- the first two books of a trilogy by David Gerrold (concluded in *Leaping to the Stars*).  The first novel involves conflict aboard a climber on the space elevator, while the second has a hidden Lunar colony, which the protagonists reach by crossing a long stretch of open surface in ball-like emergency pressure suits.

Comment: Agreed, that's my thought as well.